# ERROR CS0234 namespace name 'Encodings' does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following the [Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller) on Adding Controllers and came across the following errors:

1) CS0234   The type or namespace name 'Encodings' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

2) CS0103   The name 'HtmlEncoder' does not exist in the current context    WebMVC2

Below is the code I currently have:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace WebMVC2.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    { 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/
        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is my default action...";
        }

        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 
        public string Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
        {
            return HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode($"Hello {name}, NumTimes is: {numTimes}");
        }
```

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 and have the .NET Core SDK 2.1.3

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: Well that tutorial is for Asp.Net Core.  Are you using Asp.Net Core?  .Net Core and Asp.Net Core are **not** the same thing.

Comment: Similarly, also `ASP.NET MVC` and `.NET Core MVC` are not the same. Check which template you used to generate your application.

Answer (score 1):

Amy who commented on your post is correct, you are not using an ASP.Net Core project/solution.

The problem is, .Net Core SDK 2.1.3 is not the same asp ASP.Net core (Which the tutorial is for.)

[image: Image of select new project]

Once in here, type "ASP.Net Core" in the upper right corner as seen on this:

[image]

Then you will have loaded the correct assemblies for your tutorial.